# Help in understanding block header input data for scrypt

Tags: litecoin, scrypt, block-header

I am an computer engineering student trying to understand how the Litecoin scrypt algorithm works. I downloaded the Github cp-uminer. Can someone give me some examples what the input data look like for the miner's scanhash_scrypt function input argument work.data? I know it is a 640-bit (80 byte) header. But I can't find any document that describes the fields of the header, little-endian/big-endian etc.

Also, some comparison with bitcoin's SHA confuses me. In the cpu-miner's scrypt.c, it takes input argument data and runs SHA256 transform on it. For Bitcoin, I would see that there is a conversion to big-endian before running the SHA256 transform. Is this expected?

Thanks!

Regards,
SC

Comment: This is exactly the same thing i was searching for.. Did you find any solutions? It seems that there is really not a lot of documentation regarding the constructing the block in general properly and applying scrypt algorithm on it.